# MySQL mutual dependent tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, circular-dependency

I'm creating 2 tables, one called *users* and the other called *images*, each user can have one avatar which refers to an image in *image* table, yet each image has an author to identify who uploaded/created the image, and this author references to a user in *user* table, and I added foreign key constraints for both, so these 2 tables become mutually dependent, and that makes the insert/delete operation a mess... I wonder if anyone could come up with a better design pattern maybe, like creating another table or anything so I can avoid this mutual dependent situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as mysql does not provide a way to perform deferred constraint checks the only way to do it for you is to disable constraint checks at all with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

and then enable it back as soon as you are done

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

But you need to be very careful and not break database integrity while you're in a "sparta"-mode.

PS: this option is session-specific, so the other connections will still respect constraints as usually.

PPS: as soon as you're going to put your DB into a broken state - I highly recommend to make all the changes in a single transaction, so that other sessions could not observe the inconsistent state.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a design to avoid being mutually dependant, this feels like some hack... Besides, I can't and won't temporarily disable foreign key checks everytime user updates an avatar and enable it back after the avatar updated...

Comment: @dulan: I don't see anything bad in having 2 way dependencies. It does not violate any Normal Forms or other "best practices" I'm aware of.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just thought one way dependency is simpler for design and has less code and would like to keep it that way.